# explain MongoDB date format

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoose, time

For defining a model in `node.js` I am using mongoose library and I want to store the date in that.
here is the schema:

```
availability: [
    {
        day: {
            type: String,
        },
        startTime: {
            type: Date,
        },
        endTime: {
            type: Date,
        },
    },
]
```

I am passing the value from postman like below:

```
{
    "parkingId":"62cfa09adb8bc68f045b4d65",
    "day":"Monday",
    "startTime":7,
    "endTime": 22
}
```

But it is getting saved like this from 1970. I am aware that passing a time like this will calculate time from **Unix epoch** But I want to save today's date or date passed by merchant user for availability

```
day:Monday,
startTime: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.007+00:00"),
endTime: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.022+00:00")
```

And also what is `007+00:00 or 022+00:00`?

Should I use moment library for that?

Comment: What is 7 and what is 22? `007+00:00 or 022+00:00` are microseconds part of the datetime.

Comment: Instead of `"Monday"` you should store week day as number - preferably according to ISO-8601, i.e. Monday = 1 to Sunday = 7. It will save you a lot of coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to MongoDB, this is a `mongoose` feature.

You define `startTime` and `endTime` as `Date` in your schema, but you are passing a number. let's see what the `mongoose` code does in this scenraio:

```
function castDate(value) {

  ...

  let date;

  if (value instanceof Number || typeof value === 'number') {
    date = new Date(value);
  }

  ...
};
```

As you can see in the case the input value is a `number` which is the case here, the `mongoose` schema casts this value to date using js [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) function which is basically:

> JavaScript Date objects represent a single moment in time in a platform-independent format. Date objects contain a Number that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

This means when it casts `new Date(7)` the result is `1 January 1970 UTC` + `7 mili seconds` whichi is the `7` your seeing in the result `1970-01-01T00:00:00.007+00:00`

Clearly in your case all you need to do is change the `Date` type to `Number` which is actually what you're trying to save.

Comment: Thank you for explanation but then how should I pass the time or how mongoose schema should look like?

Comment: You are not saving a date, but just an hour. so in your case you can just put type Number instead.

If you're actually trying to save a date then you should pass the proper date object to match.

Comment: Ok, if I store time as a number then is it possible to filter the data based on that. (like user wants to see the availability at the startTime of 10 and endTime of 14).

Comment: Yes it's possible, the schema is problematic in my opinion because "Monday" doesn't mean much in code, it's quite hard to answer without knowing the full picture.

Comment: Ok, so for that should I use moment.js library? and then convert that day into date and filter the data based on that.

Comment: `moment` is deprecated, I find the js `Date` function to be satisfactory most times. it would be a good idea to save an actual date yes.

Comment: For new projects you should not use `moment`. Use [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)